# How many solutions are there to $x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} + x_{4} = 15$

Tags: combinatorics

**How many solutions are there to** (I think they mean non-negative integer solutions)
$x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} + x_{4} = 15$

**where**

$1\leq x_{1} \leq 4$

$2 \leq x_{2} \leq 5$

$7\leq x_{3}$

$2\leq x_{4}$

**My "Solution"**
I use the method shown in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y0CYHMqomgI&list=PLDDGPdw7e6Aj0amDsYInT_8p6xTSTGEi2&index=7

$$N(\overline{C_{1}}\overline{C_{2}}\overline{C_{3}}\overline{C_{4}}) = $$

$$ N - (N_{C1}+N_{C2}+N_{C3}+N_{C4}) + N_{C1C2}+ N_{C1C3}+ N_{C1C4}+ N_{C2C3}+ N_{C2C4}+N_{C3C4}  - N_{C1C2C3} - N_{C1C2C4} - N_{C1C3C4} - N_{C2C3C4} + N_{C1C2C3C4}$$

$$N=\binom{18}{15}$$

Now this part (find NC1) i am unsure about. when $$1\leq x_{1} \leq 4$$
$$N_{C1}$$ 
$$x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} + x_{4} = 15$$  $$1\leq x_{1} \leq 4$$

$$ x_{1}{}' + x_{2} + x_{3} + x_{4} = 15 -4 = 11$$ $$x_{1}{}' \geq 0$$

$$N_{C1} =\binom{14}{11}$$

Is this the right way to find $$N_{C1} $$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Substituting 
$$\begin{cases}
y_1=x_1-1\\
y_2=x_2-2\\
y_3=x_3-7\\
y_4=x_4-2
\end{cases}$$
your problem becomes equivalent to finding $y_1,\ldots,y_4$ satisfying $$\begin{split}0&\leq y_1\leq 3,\\0&\leq y_2\leq 3,\\0&\leq y_3,\\0&\leq y_4\end{split}$$ and $$y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4=3.$$ The solution to this are $$y=(y_1,\ldots,y_4)=(3,0,0,0)$$ (and other permutations, making up a total of $4$), $$y=(2,1,0,0)$$ (and other permutations, making up a total of $4!/2!=12$), and $$y=(1,1,1,0)$$ (and other permutations, making up $4$). The number of solutions then is $$4+12+4=20.$$

Comment: Ok thanks i will try to learn this. Why is $y_1 + y_2 + y_3 + y_4 = 3$ ?

Comment: Because of the substitution, we have $y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4=(x_1-1)+(x_2-2)+(x_3-7)+(x_4-2)=(x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4)-12=15-12=3$.

Comment: $$y = (y_{1},....y_{4}) = (3,0,0,0)$$ what does this mean, is it supposed to be equal to 4 ?

Comment: you can omit the $\le 3$ for $y_1, y_2$ so you get the number of [**weak** Compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28combinatorics%29) which is in fact 20.

Comment: $$y = (2,1,0,0)$$ and that part is supposed  to be equal to 12? Sorry for dumb questions, just trying to understand your solution.

Comment: @DanielAndersson if one of $y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4$ is $3$ and the others are $0$, then there are precisely $4$ ways in which this is possible: $(3,0,0,0),(0,3,0,0),(0,0,3,0),(0,0,0,3)$. With $(2,1,0,0)$, there are $12$ ways (you can try to list them for yourselve). In general, if you have $n=m_1+\ldots+m_k$ where the $k\geq1$ integers $m_1,\ldots,m_k\geq0$ then the number of permutations of $k$ distinguishable objects $i=1,\ldots,k$ each with appearance $m_i$ is equal to $n!/(m_1!\cdots m_k!)$.

Comment: Thanks! So i guess we can get 4 from $$y = (1,1,1,0)$$ because $$\frac{4!}{3!} = 4$$

Comment: Completely correct!

Answer (score 2):

Write $y_1=x_1-1$, $y_2=x_2-2$, $y_3-7$ and  $y_4-2$, then $y_i \geq 0$, $y_1,y_2\leq 3$ and $$y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4 = 3$$

But then $y_3$ and $y_4$ can not be 4 or more. So $y_1,y_2\leq 3$ is not actual restriction here. By stars and bars method we have $${6\choose 3}=20$$ solution.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\sum_{x_{1} = 1}^{4}\sum_{x_{2} = 2}^{5}
\sum_{x_{3} = 7}^{\infty}\sum_{x_{4} = 2}^{\infty}
\bracks{z^{15}}z^{x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} + x_{4}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\sum_{x_{1} = 0}^{3}\sum_{x_{2} = 0}^{3}
\sum_{x_{3} = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{x_{4} = 0}^{\infty}
\bracks{z^{15}}z^{\pars{x_{1} + 1} + \pars{x_{2} + 2} + \pars{x_{3} + 7} + \pars{x_{4} + 2}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bracks{z^{3}}\sum_{x_{1} = 0}^{3}z^{x_{1}}
\sum_{x_{2} = 0}^{3}z^{x_{2}}
\sum_{x_{3} = 0}^{\infty}z^{x_{3}}\sum_{x_{4} = 0}^{\infty}z^{x_{4}} =
\bracks{z^{3}}\pars{z^{4} - 1 \over z - 1}^{2}
\pars{1 \over 1 - z}^{2}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bracks{z^{3}}\pars{1 - z}^{-4} = {-4 \choose 3}\pars{-1}^{3} =
-{-\pars{-4} + 3 - 1 \choose 3}\pars{-1}^{3}
\\[5mm] = &\ {6 \choose 3} = \bbx{20} 
\end{align}